# Synapse Spark write to different /mount point [or] container

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-synapse

Am trying to write DataFrame from Synapse spark as .delta into a container.

Here is the example code:

```
sqlstmt = 'select * from tableblah limit 5'
df = spark.sql(sqlstmt)
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/bronze/account")
```

What this is doing is it's into Synapse's Primay ADLS Gen2 file system (ex: container name 'synapsews', now file written is in synapsews container /bronze/account.

How can i mount different container and write into it.

I tried mounting 'devbronze' container as below:

```
mssparkutils.fs.mount(
"abfss://devbronze@dlsdataxxxxdirdev001.dfs.core.windows.net",
"/devbronze",
{ "linkedService":"LS_synapsews" }
```

)

now when tried to write this mount as below:

```
df.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save("/devbronze/account")
```

it still write to Primay ADLS Gen2 file system which is synapsews by creating /devbronze/account folders.

How to change to write to mounted point 'devbronze'

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the same way as yours in my environment and ended up with same result. Here `synapsedata` is my primary file system for the synapse workspace.

[image]

To store the files in the mount point other than the primary file system, we can use the path like `synfs:/<jobid>/<mountpoint>/<path>`.

Use the below code which is working for me to achieve your requirement.

```
jobid=mssparkutils.env.getJobId()
path='synfs:/'+jobid+'/devbronze/account'
print(path)

df1.write.format("delta").mode("overwrite").save(path)
```

First get the **job id** from `mssparkutils` and build the path with your mount location. Here `devbronze` is my mount point and container name which was created by using linked service.

[image]

**Code Execution:**

[image]

**Result files in mount path:**

[image]